# Como contabilizar a quantidade em variavel utilizando boxplot, nao a frequencia?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico, plot

Estou tentando criar um boxplot da quantidade de respiradores por estado, mas quando vou plotar o R contabiliza a frequência de respiradores não a quantidade em si. Ai tenho a seguinte informação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que as quantidades sejam somadas, não que ele utilize a frequência. Como posso fazer isso?

Download do banco de dados:
https://dados.gov.br/dataset/distribuicao-de-respiradores

Segue script:

```
distribuicao_respiradores <- read.csv2("~/distribuicao_respiradores.csv", encoding="UTF-8", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
View(distribuicao_respiradores)
attach(distribuicao_respiradores)

library(ggplot2)

boxplotgraf <- ggplot(distribuicao_respiradores, aes(x=DESTINO, y=QUANTIDADE))

boxplotgraf + geom_boxplot(outlier.color = "red") +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(y="Quantidade") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Não tem nenhum erro no seu código, esses boxplots são das quantidades. Se o que quer é apenas o total por Estado, boxplots não são para isso.

Comment: É como o @CarlosEduardoLagosta comentou. Boxplots, são para ver a distribuição, com medianas , quartis  e etcs. Acho que você quer é um histograma.